# 2 Different Permissions for Android Project

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

we are working on a project and we want to make 2 version for it.

One that requires permissions for paid services (like SMS, Phone Calls etc...) and one without them.

We are looking for a way to integrate it in one project so we don't have to keep track of changes in 2 projects and so we won't have 2 different source files just for this minor difference.

Is there a way to set 2 sets of permissions and decide which one do we want on compile time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store the project files in a repository, like `git`. The github app from github.com, or the sourcetree app from the mac app store, will do that in a GUI, and they're both free. Having put your code into git, you'll have a "master" branch. Create a "freebie" branch in git. That will have all the sources in your master branch, initially. Change the code you need to in your freebie branch to remove permissions - make this the only function of just one file, for simplicity. Do your development in the master branch and compile there. Switch back and forth between branches in the github/sourcetree app.

When you want to compile a freebie version, in git, switch to the freebie branch. Then use the git merge command - it's integrated into the github app - to copy the changed files from master into freebie. That should be a one-button no-humans-involved operation unless you change the same file in both branches. Then do your normal compile and you'll get the freebie app. When you switch branches in git, git swaps all the files in your source tree for the ones in the other branch, so it all just works.

For a much cleverer way of using git, which I highly recommend, you could try http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Yes, but won't this make conflicts in the Manifest.xml file every time that we merge, the content will be different?

Comment: No, at least not as long as the Manifest.xml in freebie was changed after you branched, and you don't change the Manifest.xml in master. Git realises that you've made a change in freebie and you probably want to keep it, and doesn't overwrite it with the one in master, but it does change all the other files that are newer in master. If you do change the Manifest.xml in master, you probably want to update the one in freebie somehow, and the merge operation gives you tools for doing that too.

Comment: What about the "android:required" option for the uses-permission tag? Won't it do it? Or is it only for device filterring?

Comment: I don't think you can put `android:required` in a `uses-permission`. `required` is for `uses-feature`, to specify what sort of device the app is suitable for. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library project with all the code that is common to both apps. Then include the library project in two application projects and implement all application specific things there.

Answer (score 0):

OK So after some research and Googling I got the answer that suits me!

MAVEN! I wrote a pom.xml file that has 2 profiles and I can provide in cmd line which profile I want and according to these profiles it copies relevant files (like let's say AndroidManifest.xml) from the right folder to the project's folder and compiles and deploys it to the phone.

This way I need to maintain 2 separate manifest files but I don't have to deal with possible merge and conflict problems with SVN and no need for library code.

Hope this answer helps someone and I want to thank the people that answered here as well! :)